# How to do inner joins between two entities in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, inner-join

I want to do a inner join query from the repository. The original query looks like this:

```
select p.id_persona,p.nombre,p.appaterno,p.apmaterno, bp.fecha_ingreso,bp.fecha_salida 
from bitacora_personas as bp
inner join persona as p on p.id_persona=bp.fk_id_persona 
where p.fk_id_empresa= :idEmpresa
```

I have the method in the Repository like this:

```
@Repository("bitacoraPersonasRepository")
public interface BitacoraPersonasRepository extends JpaRepository<BitacoraPersonas, Serializable> {
    @Query(value = "select p.id_persona,p.nombre,p.appaterno,p.apmaterno, bp.fecha_ingreso,bp.fecha_salida from bitacora_personas as bp\n" +
            "inner join persona as p on p.id_persona=bp.fk_id_persona\n" +
            "where p.fk_id_empresa= :idEmpresa",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public List<BitacoraPersonas> getPersonasPorEmpresa(@Param("idEmpresa") Integer idEmpresa);
}
```

When I try to run this it throws me an error saying that the `id_bitacora_personas` column from BitacoraPersonas entity doesn't exists, even when the column in the table exists. I think it is because the Persona entity doesn't have that column, and when I try to run the method `getPersonasPorEmpresa()` from the controller which return a List of `BitacoraPersonas`, it doesn´t work with the `Persona` entity because they are not correctly mapped or something. As you can see I'm trying to retrieve attributes from the `Persona` entity as so from the `BitacoraPersona` entity in the inner join. How can I solve this?

Comment: You are correct that `HQL` can join on entity properties but not table columns. Does the provided native query not work?

Comment: @TheHeadRush No, it doesn't work. It throws me the next error
`inner join persona as p on p.id_persona=bp.fk_id_persona
where p.fk_id_empresa= ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id_bitacora_personas' not found.`

Comment: You aren't selecting `id_bitacora_personas` in that query. Your result set needs to include each a column for each mapped property in the entity.

Comment: @TheHeadRush How can I do this?

Comment: think a hql-query could work: ```select bp from BitacoraPersonas  bp
join fkIdPersona p where p.idPersona = :idEmpresa ```

Comment: @DirkDeyne but with this query I can get the attributes from the Persona entity? like nombre, appaterno, apmaterno, etc.

Comment: @PaulMiranda yes you should have access to all none LAZY fetched fields

Comment: @DirkDeyne When I try to run the code with the query it throws me a very extends error that say this: `antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!`
The query looks like this:
` @Query("select bp from BitacoraPersonas bp join fkIdPersona p where p.idPersona = :idEmpresa")
    public List<BitacoraPersonas> ga(@Param("idEmpresa") Integer idEmpresa);`

Comment: @PaulMiranda  bp.fkIdPersona

Comment: It worked :) thanks a lot